# fullcalendar performance with more than 100 events

Tags: performance, fullcalendar

I had a problem with performance when rendering many events. The events are obtained from a database with php and the function is optimized, 1 second max, but the redrawing of the calendar takes about 15 seconds.

After simplify, this is my eventRender code:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) 
{
element.attr('title', event.title + '\u000d' + event.tipo + '\u000d' + event.estado);
}
```

I had no eventAfterAllRender code.

This is events code:

```
events: {
url: 'obtener_citas_dia.php',
type: 'POST', 
error: function() {
alert('Error recuperando eventos.');
}
},
```

In PHP, the recordset from mysql is converted to an array:

```
while($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
$arr[] = $row;
}
```

And encoded:

```
json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Could you provide `eventRender` and `eventAfterAllRender` code? From my experience performance issues could happen there.

Comment: that is a lot of events, but still I'm surprised it takes quite so long. How are you adding them - as a hard-coded array, or via a separate ajax request? Please show some code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ADyson. I hope you'll have enough information

Comment: Ok.  If you remove the code from `eventRender`, does it make any difference to the loading time?

Comment: @ADyson. There is no difference without eventRender. I have just noticed thet the execution time this morning was about 15 seconds, but now (there is nobody working) it is about 5 seconds. Could it be server load? The SQL is fast in both cases, but rendering or redrawing not

Comment: Narrow down the problem - run each part separately: 1) Run the SQL separately in Workbench or something. Then, run obtener_citas_dia.php directly in a browser, on the server where it's hosted. Then run your fullCalendar page and use the Network tools to watch the AJAX request to obtener_citas_dia.php, and also see how long it is before the events actually appear on screen. In each case above, time how long the task takes to complete. Looking at the differences in the timings will give you an idea whether the problem is in the SQL, the PHP script, the network bandwidth or the fullCalendar code.